# Exclude a module or dir or subtask from gradle configuration and execution

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, junit5

I have a task with name `test` and code is as below :

```
tasks {
    "test"(Test::class) {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            excludeTags = setOf("e2e", "integration")
        }    
 }
```

When execute this task with gradle command `./gradlew test --info`, gradle is scanning all the modules of my project and generating a configuration with has some tasks from module named `data-export-ui-kjs`.

I want gradle to exclude the tasks from `data-export-ui-kjs` module while configuring & executing `test` task. I have used below code to achieve this but its not successful

```
 gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        TaskExecutionGraphListener { graph ->
                if(it.name.contains("data-export-ui-kjs")) {
                    it.enabled = false
                }
            }    
     }
```

Kindly help me to get this done. Thanks in advance

Comment: The task names don't contain the name of the module they belong to. Using the task's `path` instead of `name` should work.

Comment: modified code is as below. But still gradle configures and executes tasks of data-export-ui-kjs module :                                      tasks {
    "test"(Test::class) {
        useJUnitPlatform {
            excludeTags = setOf("e2e", "integration")
        }
        gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
            TaskExecutionGraphListener { graph ->
                graph.allTasks.forEach { task ->
                    if(task.path.contains("data-export-ui-kjs")) {
                        task.enabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working as expected. Modified the code. Its syntax issue itseems